# Chinese string input for python?

Tags: python, cjk

How can I get python to work with simplified Chinese text input either as strings or raw input?

Comment: What OS are you using and what default language is it configured for?  I use Windows XP and English.  I can't type Chinese at a cmd.exe console, but using an editor such as PythonWin or even Notepad it is no problem to work with Chinese if the Microsoft Pinyin IME is installed.  If I alter the default language for non-Unicode programs to Chinese, I can then work with Chinese in a cmd.exe window as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Decode on input](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).

```
u = s.decode('gb2312')
```

Comment: 'gb2312' encoding and decodeing seems unavaile to my Python 2.6.5rc1 installation

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then. It's working fine here on 2.6.2. Perhaps there's another package you need to install in order to get the codec.

Comment: I think on some Linux distros it mightn't be installed - you may need to install them from http://cjkpython.i18n.org/

Comment: Reverted back to python 2.6.2 and captured input with raw_input().  That works.  Probably in 2.6.5 also but I did not try it.

>>s = raw_input("Insert Chinese Text Here: ")
你好世界
>>u'\u4f60\u597d\u4e16\u754c'
>> print s
>> 你好世界

Answer (score 0):

Trivial handling of Chinese characters in python 2.6.2 32 bit on windows vista 64 bit

```
>>> s = raw_input("Insert Chinese Text Here: ")

    你好世界

>>> u'\u4f60\u597d\u4e16\u754c'

>>> print s

你好世界

>>>
```